# mysql.connector.cursor.execute() proceeds silently but makes no changes despite commit()

Tags: python, mysql

I need to execute certain MySQL commands in a python script, which is a straight-forward task. For testing purposes I have boiled down the commands to this:

```py
import mysql.connector

script = """
CREATE DATABASE `new_project`;

CREATE TABLE `new_project`.`category` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `unq_name` (`name`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
"""

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port="3306",
    user="root",
    passwd="somepassword",
)
cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
    print("begin execution")

    cursor.execute(script, multi=True)

    warnings = cursor.fetchwarnings()
    if warnings:
        for warning in warnings:
            print(warning)

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    print("connection closed")

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err.msg)
```

The user credentials are replaced with the correct information when running the script.
The output of this script is

```
begin execution
connection closed
```

with no errors, warnings or other output. The database `new_project` is not created. When I run the same MySQL commands in another interface, they work as expected and create the database and the table.

I must be overlooking something very simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) of `execute` mentions that the method returns an iterator with the results for each query when `multi=True`. It seems the queries are not doing anything until the iterator has been processed, regardless of `commit()`. However, `CREATE` statements do not produce any results and trying to iterate over the return value of `execute` results in an exception: `generator raised StopIteration`. This is related to [a bug in the connector module](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87818) and has been fixed in version 8.0.13 with support of python 3.7.

The solution is now to always iterate over the return value of `execute`, even if no return data is expected, and to upgrade the connector module. If the upgrade is not feasible it is possible to catch the failed iteration and continue.

The fixed code (including the part for earlier versions of the connector module) now looks something like this:

```py
try:
    results = cursor.execute(script, multi=True)
    try:
        for result in results:
            pass
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    warnings = cursor.fetchwarnings()
    if warnings:
        for warning in warnings:
            # handle warning

    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    # handle error
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using password="somepassword" instead of passwd="somepassword". And remove multi=True. It'll create a warning but will still execute both of your statements.

Comment: The ```passwd``` is a good catch, thanks. The documentation says it's a synonym but also mentions not to rely on it. Disabling the ```multi``` option does, strangely against expectations, work even if ```comiit()``` is never called. However I think I found the reason why the original code doesn't work and have a solution that works with ```multi``` and hopefully will not break once the bug in the connector module has been fixed.